# Почему не работает метод getText?

Tags: java, swing, строки, text

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class cPanel extends JPanel
{

    public cPanel()
    {
        setLayout(null);

        JTextArea textIN = new JTextArea();
        textIN.setBounds(0,15,600,100);
        add(textIN);

        JTextArea textOut = new JTextArea();
        textOut.setBounds(0,135,600,100);
        textOut.setVisible(true);
        add(textOut);

        JButton btnGJD = new JButton("CHANGE");
        btnGJD.setBounds(700,75,100,100);
        add(btnGJD);

        char[] chars = {'[',']'};
        String IN = textIN.getText();//////////////???????/////////////
        String[] tmp = IN.split(" ");

        btnGJD.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {

                String tmpfinal = String.valueOf(Arrays.asList(tmp[0])).replace('[',' ').replace(']',' ');
                textOut.append(tmpfinal.trim().concat("ka"));
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Что значит "не работает"? Возвращает пустую строку? NPE кидает?

Comment: Возвращает пустой элемент массива. Без исключений. Пробовал просто textOut. append(IN); ничего не отображает.

Comment: Может дело в том, что текста нема в текстовом поле?...

Comment: @ЮрийСПб ну я вводил :)

Comment: Но на момент ввода ведь tmp ничего в себе не имеет же.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы используете в слушателе нажатий массив, коий пуст на момент создания. Вам надо заново его наполнить в момент нажатия

```
btnGJD.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String IN = textIN.getText();
        String[] tmp = IN.split(" ");
        String tmpfinal = String.valueOf(Arrays.asList(tmp[0])).replace('[',' ').replace(']',' ');
        textOut.append(tmpfinal.trim().concat("ka"));
    }
});
```

Comment: Господи... Что-то не то с головой, нужно кофе выпить. Спасибо большое.